# Save Config button isn't working in System > Configuration > Catalog

Tags: configuration

My recently viewed product is not displaying anything, so I am trying to change my Recently Viewed "Show for current" settings from Website to Store to see if that will make it work.

Problem: When I click Save Config after making changes in System > Configuration > Catalog nothing happens.

The Save Config button works everywhere else within the site. The console in Chrome only shows a warning that doesn't seem to be triggered by the Save Config: **event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.**

Comment: that warning is no issue as far as I know. If there aren't any other javascript errors can you check your system.log and error.log?

Comment: Do you have custom/3rd party module that adds options to that configuration area? (any of the sections in System > Configuration > Catalog)

Comment: No javascript error is returned when the page loads or when the save config button is clicked. Nothing is logged in system.log or exception.log before or after the click.

Edit: I do not have an error.log file.

Comment: Which magento Version do you use? It could be a problem which was fixed in 1.8.x

Comment: Note that there won't be any errors written to the server logfiles *directly* as a result of thisclick behavior because it is a client-side error.

Answer (score 9):

Open all the fieldsets in the catalog tab. Most probably there is a field in one of them that is not valid and there is a js error message that prevents the form from submitting.
If you open all of them you should see the one with problems.

Comment: I am also having a similar kind of issue. I am not getting any error, it is just not being able to send any data in this catalog save and thereby unable to save.

Comment: try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area adminthml